# Animated MoPub (AdMob native) ads overlayed on a game black out screen

Tags: android, admob, andengine, mopub

I've got a game based on AndEngine using MoPub ads with the AdMob adapter, and with v6.1.0 of the AdMob SDK. I'm using the latest mopub-client code pulled from GitHub today. I've also tried this after removing the native adapter.

I display ads using a FrameLayout which contains a SurfaceView and the MoPubView.

The device I'm testing on is a 4.1 (Jelly Bean) Galaxy Nexus.

Problem is, when the ad happens to be one with multiple frames, as the frames change, the rest of the screen goes blank (i.e., the game vanishes and users are left with a black screen with the banner ad still dutifully rendering in the top)

This seems to occur more frequently if I leave the app then return to it.

Also, if I make a dialog appear (with the back button), the game will reappear behind it until I :
1) dismiss the dialog
2) wait for the next frame in the banner ad animation

Any ideas how I can debug this further, or has anyone encountered this before and knows what I need to do? Is there a better alternative method for overlaying a banner on a SurfaceView?

Cheers

Comment: I have a same issue. Have you found the solution？

Comment: I have not, and MoPub hasn't responded to a request for support. Of course the problem could be with admob in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had the same problem on a Nexus 7 and it was solved with:

adView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);